# Automatically Login in external service when viewing webmap

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, arcgis-online-webmap

I want to consume some external ESRI service in my webmap which has credentials enabled on it.Though, I have credentials to access it, but I want that service to be available to all my organization members as a layer in Webmap, and they should be able to view this service without logging in to that service once they opens up the webmap.

Please guide me on how to implement such behavior.

Comment: You need to set up a group for that https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/groups.htm

Comment: @Mapperz, Point is not about set up a group and then sharing, I have even tried putting that webmap as public but even then also that external service is asking for credentials. I want that service to be accessible to all the users inside my organization so that they don't have to put credentials in it.